# Deploy an SSL enabled Java SpringBoot war to External Tomcat Server

Tags: tomcat, ssl, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application, which is an SSL enabled one, I can access it through localhost. "https://localhost:8443/showPage" like this. For localhost I created SSL certificate and gave the details in application.properties like below

```
server.port: 8443
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: 123456
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

This works perfectly for localhost. I want to deploy the war to a tomcat server, which is already SSL enabled. For that I changed the properties like below

```
server.port: 8443
server.ssl.key-store: /opt/tomcat/keystore/keystorefile.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password: Rv$@1234
server.ssl.keyStoreType: JKS
server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

But I am getting the below image while accessing any request. I called the request properly. Not as shown in the picture. Like this:  "https://ipaddress:8443/war_name/showPage"
[image]

And my controller accepts request for 
@RequestMapping("showPage")

Comment: The `server.*` properties are useless when deploying to a container. Those are only useful when running the jar/war and to configure the embedded container.

Answer (score 3):

I spent days looking for an answer so I will post my solution for someone else to follow here. I am using Spring Boot 2 with an external tomcat 9 running on centOs 8.

1. Get an SSL certificate, I created a self-signed cert using keytool with a password.
2. Store the jks and the p12 file on your apache server. I stored it in /opt/tomcat
3. Edit your apache server.xml file to have something like this.

   ```
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
     maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
     keystoreFile="/opt/tomcat/keystore.p12" keystorePass="password" 
     clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1"/>
   ```
4. Restart Tomcat
5. Open the firewall port for 8443 and restart the firewall daemon

   ```
     firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port 8443/tcp
     firewall-cmd --reload
   ```

It is very quick once you know what the steps are! Just don't forget anything.

Comment: what changes you did in spring configuration?